# Is there any Eclipse plugin for firefox extension creation?

Tags: eclipse, firefox, eclipse-plugin, firefox-addon

I have starting creating my first firefox extension. I am following 
http://extensions.roachfiend.com/howto_bug.html

But seems creating this without an IDE is very tedious task. Do we have any eclipse plugin for creating firefox extension? Or is there any tool for firefox extension creation?

Comment: Please correct your question. If Spket is answer to it, then it isn't about Eclipse plugin. I don't see here anything about Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Spket](http://www.spket.com/download.html) in the past.  I find it particularly useful for generating an initial skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out [Extension Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7434/) if you haven't yet. It's not really an IDE but it comes with lots of helpful tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the addon SDK from Mozilla.

With this it is very easy to create a skeleton for your addon and it is VERY easy to compile (to create an `.xpi`).

But this is no IDE, so the operations are console based, but it has a big advantage! You don't need to create a new Profile in Firefox for developing extensions / addons. With the SDK and with the operation `cfx run`, a new instance of Firefox is created with a temporary profile.

This will be deleted after the window is closed.